typescript-eslint checks files not included in 'files' directive
I'm using @eslint/js 9.14 and typescript-eslint 8.13, and I'm using the following configuration (removed some rules for brevity:)
export default tseslint.config({
 
  files: ['src/**/*.ts', 'test/**/*.ts'],

  extends: [ 
    eslint.configs.recommended,
    ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  ],
  rules: {
    indent: ["error", 2, {
      SwitchCase: 1,
    }],

    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],

    "no-constant-condition": ["error", {
      checkLoops: false,
    }],

    quotes: ["error", "single", {
      allowTemplateLiterals: false,
      avoidEscape: true,
    }],

    semi: ["error", "always"],

    "no-console": ["error", {
      allow: ["warn", "error", "info", "debug"],
    }],
  },
});

I would expect this configuration to only check the src and test directory, but unfortunately this also checks my dist/ and bin/ directory, which contains Typescript compiled files. Some examples of errors:
[redacted]/bin/generate-db-types.mjs
  2:1  warning  Unused eslint-disable directive (no problems were reported)

[redacted]/dist/api-types.js
  1:1  warning  Unused eslint-disable directive (no problems were reported)

[redacted]/dist/mfa/webauthn/controller/attestation.js
  49:13  warning  Unused eslint-disable directive (no problems were reported from 'no-console')


